# ASP .NET invalid path

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

I have a web page which prompts the user for an excel file using the fileupload control. What it then does is read the file into a datatable using an OleDbConnection and then runs other code with that data. When I test in Visual Studio, it works fine. For example, I can look up a file 'g:\myfiles\upldtest.xls', it finds the file, reads it and the code works. When I try to run it on our web server, I get an error when it tries to create an OleDBConnection saying It is trying to create an OleDbConnection and the path 'g:\myfiles\upldtest.xls' is invalid.

I tried to use ManagementObjectSearcher to convert the connection string path to UNC (\\MyDataServer\myfiles instead of g:\myfiles). When I test it, it shows the correct path but when I upload the page to the web server, I still get the path 'g:\myfiles\upldtest.xls' is invalid.

The code I use to determine the required file name is this

string tname = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName; //the file name and path

string gname = tname.Substring(tname.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1); //The path name

Any ideas what I am missing? My contract requires me to use VS2005 and .NET framework 2.0 so, I can't use anything newer. Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: I do not think so, I get the failure on the server and I would think I have permission, unless...it is an issue with IIS 6?

Answer (score 3):

[HttpPostedFile.FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.filename%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) returns the fully qualified name of the file *on the client machine*.

You need to call [SaveAs()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.saveas%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) to actually save the file on the server:

```
using System.IO;

string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
string filepath = Path.Combine(@"X:\Your\Own\Upload\Folder", filename);
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(filepath);

// Now use `filepath` as your data source.
```

`IIS` might have already written the file in a temporary location to save memory, but since you can't (and shouldn't) access that location, it makes no difference.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response and thanks for responding. I can't transfer the file onto the server. I need to be able to read the file into memory and work with it that way. Most end users running this won't have the underlying permission to upload a file to the server.

Answer (score 2):

You should also be aware of cross-browser issues. IE sends the whole path to the server on file upload, while Firefox/Chrome do not.

Comment: For the good or the bad, we only use IE. Thanks for responding.